# Python Heroku app crashes even though it's not near memory limit

Tags: python, memory, heroku

I am deploying a Python app on Heroku and it has to load a ~40 MB JSON file. The app crashes with out of memory errors even though Heroku tells me it ought to have 512 MB of RAM. Why is this happening, and can I fix it? The error log (from heroku logs) is below:

2016-02-15T01:10:39.367715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-02-15T01:10:52.785020+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=731M(142.6%)
2016-02-15T01:10:52.785020+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

If it got stuck in a recursive loop, it would give you an out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

The in-memory representation of a variable or structure is much larger than the file representation. For example,

```
import sys

sys.getsizeof({})       # => 288 bytes
sys.getsizeof([])       # => 64 bytes
sys.getsizeof("abc")    # => 52 bytes
sys.getsizeof(12)       # => 28 bytes
```

*(Note that these values were obtained using Cython 3.4 64bit on Windows 10; your values may vary depending on your os and version of python.)*

I did a quick test: a 33 KB .json file became 188 KB in memory. Depending on how deeply-nested your data is, it is quite possible that a 40 MB file could take 350 MB of memory to unpack, and that's not including other memory used by your program / OS / etc.